# avoid hibernate lazy initialization exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two classes called Lecturer and Course. My Lecturer class has a List of Course objects a variable as shown

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lecturer")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

In my course class I have a Lecturer object as a variable as below.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "course_lecturer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lecturer_id"))
private Lecturer lecturer;
```

Now I have a spring Controller method that returns a json object of Lecturer as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getlecturerbyid", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Object getLecturer(@ModelAttribute(value = "id") Lecturer lecturer) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("message", "succeess");
    response.put("lecturer", lecturer);
    return response;
}
```

The problem is it throws a lazy initialization exception. Therefore I set fetch type in both variables in Lecturer and Course class to eager. Now the problem is it infinitely tries to fetch objects eagerly(if I unset fetch of either, it raises the same exception).

On the other hand if I remove the variable of either class, then the hibernate does not know that there is a relationship for another. eg: if I remove course list from Lecturer and delete one of the Lecturer objects then hibernate does not remove the course objects that are related with the deleted Lecturer object. so i have to write a hibernate query and remove it manually in the code.

Can you please suggest me on how to over come this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of **circular reference(parent -> child ->parent)**. I am sure you have got the idea.

The simplest solution for your problem is to iterate the list of courses and set the `Lecturer` as null before putting it into `response` to break the circular relationship as below:

```
   Object getLecturer(@ModelAttribute(value = "id") Lecturer lecturer) {
       Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       response.put("message", "succeess");

       //break the circular relationship
       if(lecturer.getCourses() != null){
          for(Course course: lecturer.getCourses()){
               course.setLecturer(null);
          }
       }
       response.put("lecturer", lecturer);
       return response;
   }
```

Comment: Which one is it that can't handle the circular-reference like that, Hiberante or Spring?

Comment: @BheshGurung The serialization when it is added into response.

Comment: I am not sure, but looks like it's the JSON serializer, that's failing here.

Comment: @YogendraSingh : yes it is the serialization that causes problems and your method is working for me. Thank you !!!

Comment: @YogendraSingh: Doesn't your solution assumes that the initialization is eager

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal: What will happen if its not?

Comment: Actually now I understand it doesn't really matters what the initialization is :)

Comment: This discussion provides a more neat method to address this problem !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778970/a-better-way-to-avoid-hibernate-lazy-init-exception-when-serializing-in-to-a-jso

Comment: @madhumal: The other answer is very specific to `Jackson`.

Comment: @YogendraSingh : yes it seems so. Both have it's pros and cons :)

Answer (score -2):

This problem can be overcome by using @JsonIgnore annotation if you are using jackson mapper.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778970/a-better-way-to-avoid-hibernate-lazy-init-exception-when-serializing-in-to-a-jso) addresses the issue for jackson.

Comment: This is very specific to `Jackson`.