# A better way to avoid hibernate lazy init exception when serializing in to a json response

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

This is in reference [to a question I asked a month back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354766/avoid-hibernate-lazy-initialization-exception).

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354766/avoid-hibernate-lazy-initialization-exception) the answer to avoid the lazy init exception when json serializing was to set null to the variables that cause lazy init exception. But consider when the class has many dependencies. Now with the code base is grown and every time I have to set null to the troublesome variables everywhere in the code to avoid json serializing problem. The method does not look neat when the code base is large.

An example code is shown below that doesn't look good.

```
//setting some variables to avoid lazy init exception in jackson mapper serialization
batch.setEnrollmentList(null);
List<BatchSchedule> scheduleList = (ArrayList<BatchSchedule>) batch.getBatchScheduleList();

            for (BatchSchedule batchSchedule : scheduleList) {
                batchSchedule.setBatch(null);
            }
            batch.getLecturer().setBatchList(null);
            batch.getLecturer().setSubjectList(null);
            batch.getSubject().setBatchList(null);
            batch.getSubject().setLecturerList(null);
```

Can you please suggest me a better way to handle this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate the lazy properties with `@JsonIgnore` so that Jackson ignores it while serializing.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. One question, does it ignore that field when deserializing also?

Comment: it seems so , http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html   I have not tried it

Comment: from json 1.9 onwards both setters and getters are ignored. If serialization is the only part to be ignored then JsonIgnore annotation need to be used in the getter method and also need to add JsonProperty annotation to the field or setter method to avoid ignoring deserialization and vise-versa. Thanks Subin for the help !!!